# How to sort Blob list in power apps

Tags: blob, powerapps

I created a list in power apps where the items fX is “azureblobstorage.ListRootFolderV2().value” how do I sort this by date?

I tried adding a sort icon and that didn’t work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Sort function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-sort) to sort the result of your call. For example, sorting by display name:

```
Sort(
  AzureBlobStorage.ListRootFolderV2().value,
  DisplayName))
```

or by the last modified date (with most recent on top):

```
Sort(
    AzureBlobStorage.ListRootFolderV2().value,
    LastModified,
    SortOrder.Descending))
```